# dplyr count within subgroup

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(Date=rep(x=as.Date(c("2016/01/01", "2016/01/02")),each=12),
       Group=rep(x=c("G1","G2"),each=6,times=2),
       ID=rep(c("G1F1","G1F2","G1F3","G1M4","G1M5","G1M6","G2F1","G2F2","G2F3","G2M4","G2M5","G2M6"),times=2),
       Gender=rep(c("Female","Male"),each=3,times=4),
       Weight=c(c(100,100,100,100,120,140),rep(c(100,120,140,100,100,100),times=2),c(100,100,100,100,120,140)))
```

I would like to create a new column `CountComp` that displays the count of same gender same group member counts of individual whose weight is within 10 gram above or below the weight of the individual specified in each row on a given date such as to get:

```
df2<-data.frame(Date=rep(x=as.Date(c("2016/01/01", "2016/01/02")),each=12),
           Group=rep(x=c("G1","G2"),each=6,times=2),
           ID=rep(c("G1F1","G1F2","G1F3","G1M4","G1M5","G1M6","G2F1","G2F2","G2F3","G2M4","G2M5","G2M6"),times=2),
           Gender=rep(c("Female","Male"),each=3,times=4),
           Weight=c(c(100,100,100,100,120,140),rep(c(100,120,140,100,100,100),times=2),c(100,100,100,100,120,140)),
           CountComp=c(c(2,2,2,0,0,0),rep(c(0,0,0,2,2,2),times=2),c(2,2,2,0,0,0)))
```

I am very new to R and thought that `dplyr` could offer a solution using `group_by` and `mutate` function, but have so far failed in finding one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
df %>% group_by(Date, Group, Gender) %>% 
    mutate(CountComp=sapply(Weight, function(x) sum(abs(x-Weight)<10)-1))
```

Here we do the `group_by` to get the classes you want to get the counts for. Then we use `mutate` to get the new column. We need to compare each value against every other value in the group. The easiest way for me to do that was to use `sapply` to look at each weight one at a time and compare it to the others, looking for differences smaller than 10.